# which is correct - jsonlint or JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have a javascript string in which a key has a value that is the *string representation* of an array:

```
{
  "a": "[\"b\",\"c\"]"
}
```

jsonlint.com says this is valid.

```
JSON.parse('{"a":"[\"b\",\"c\"]"}');
```

throws an error (unexpected token b at position 8). This seems to be about quotes containing escaped quotes - but  my string seems to conform to the standard as per www.json.org.

```
// set up an object with this pattern
var o = {};
o['a'] = "[\"b\",\"c\"]";
console.dir(o.a); // -> "[\"b\",\"c\"]"

// look at the JSON string version of this object
var j = JSON.stringify(o);
console.dir(j); // -> {"a":"[\"b\",\"c\"]"}

// set up this inside a string and try to parse it
var k = '{"a":"[\"b\",\"c\"]"}';
var l = JSON.parse(k); // -> error
```

Who is correct? jsonlint.com or JSON.parse() ?

Comment: Backslashes in a *Javascript string literal* have a meaning. If you're going to put your JSON containing backslashes into Javascript code as a string literal, you need to ensure to escape them correctly to preserve them!

Comment: Well `JSON.parse`...it's how you actually run the code. JSONLint may be faulty - the only way to check if something is valid JSON is to parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing your string in javascript, you need to escape the `\` characters or it's going to be interpreted.

```js
const ret = JSON.parse('{"a":"[\\"b\\",\\"c\\"]"}');

console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Alternatively: ``const ret = JSON.parse(String.raw`{"a":"[\"b\",\"c\"]"}`);``

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol very nice one, you should post it as an alternative answer. Is it ES7/8?

Comment: ES2015, apparently.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, using fancy modern stuff I didn't know existed until I Googled it a minute ago...

```js
const ret = JSON.parse(String.raw`{"a":"[\"b\",\"c\"]"}`);

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslashes too:

```js
var k = '{"a":"[\\"b\\",\\"c\\"]"}';
var l = JSON.parse(k);
console.log(l);
```

You could also use the [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) tag function (ES6 only):

```js
var k = String.raw`{"a":"[\"b\",\"c\"]"}`;
var l = JSON.parse(k);
console.log(l);
```